# creating an attribute with multiple tables as attribute type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with the tables A, B, C is it possible to create another Table let's call it "kind"

```
CREATE TABLE public.kind(
    name CHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
    object A, B, C
);
```

Such in this table kind is it possible to have object be either A or b or c?

Instead of doing it like this which should be possible:

```
CREATE TABLE public.kind(
    name CHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
    object_A A,
    object_B B,
    object_C C
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, yes.  You can use table inheritance.  I would recommend you read up on it in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-inheritance.html).

Basically, you say:

```
CREATE TABLE public.abc_generic (
    name CHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE public.a (
    . . .
) inherits (public.abc_generic);
```